# How to get the data from object with in object of json file using java

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception

See the following Code

```
socialMedia: 
{
      facebook: {
           profileUrl: "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Mystic-Muffin/522896574410517?rf=157791610910510"
                }
}
```

From the above we have to get the data

```
profileUrl: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Mystic-Muffin/522896574410517?rf=157791610910510
```

I am using the following code

```
JSONObject web=(JSONObject) jsonObject.get("socialMedia");
JSONObject web1=(JSONObject) jsonObject.get("facebook")
    String fburl=(String) web.get("profileUrl");
```

i am getting the java.lang.NullPointerException

Help me to get this

Comment: Well you should get the `facebook` / `profileUrl` objects from the objects before. Also it would be helpful if you posted where exactly you get the `NullPointerException` (and maybe read up on what this type of exception actually means).

Comment: thank you so much that it working. Now i am not getting the java.lang.NullPointerException @Matthias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject web=(JSONObject) jsonObject.get("socialMedia");
JSONObject web1=(JSONObject) web.get("facebook")
String fburl=(String) web1.get("profileUrl");
```